# Jquery traversing using prev()

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: prev(<selector>) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452917/jquery-prevselector-not-working)

Consider this markup:

```
<tr class="store">
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="link">link</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then this Jquery code:

```
$('.link').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').prev('.store').remove();
});
```

What I want to do is when I try to click `<a href="#" class=".store"`, the previous `<tr class="store">` should be removed. The Jquery code I posted doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: `prev` selects the previous sibling **if** it matches the selector. It does not select a preceding sibling which matches the selector. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Comment: Sidenote: You should consider using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) instead of `parents()` (but your issue will be fixed by using `prevAll()`; see the duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LP4Zb/):

```
$('.link').live('click', function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  $(this).closest('tr').prevAll('.store:eq(0)').remove();
});
```

Comment: What if there's more than one `<tr class="store"></tr>`?

Comment: It will only remove the one closest to the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Like Felix Kling said, prev selects the previous (sibling) DOM-element, not ALL previous siblings. You want to use `prevAll('.store')`

Comment: What if there's more than one `<tr class="store"></tr>`?

Answer (score 0):

.prev() only gets the immediately preceding sibling. If there is a gap between the "link row" and "store row" this will not work. You should use .prevAll() instead.

```
$('.link').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').prevAll('.store').eq(0).remove();
});
```

If you want to delete all previous "store rows" you could just remove the ".eq(0)".

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/cp33M/)